# odd File.list() behavior

Tags: java, oracle, unix

I have a Java stored procedure in the Oracle DB 11g. The Java version in Oracle is v1.5x. What it does is read files in a particular Unix directory. I've done this kind of thing before, but never against this Unix directory. This is the first time I am having this problem.

The problem is that `list()` on that directory is only returning one entry into the array that captures the results. And yes there are many other files and sub-directories in this main directory.

Doing an `ls -ltrabF` on this directory for the files I want to get produces this result:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 msdwjj   staff      26134 Dec 18 16:45 myfile.pdf
```

Doing the same `ls` command on another directory containing the same files I get:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 msdwjj   staff      26134 Dec 16 16:02 myfile.pdf
```

Yet I can read then in the later case, but not in the former case. Could it be the owner of the directory? If so, why would I be able to access one file in it and not others?

I have been working with the DBA and he has opened up permissions on that directory and all the files in it to the world, and still only this one entry - always the same one - is returned. I also checked readability of the directory using canRead() on the directory and it returns true.

This is not a filtering problem, as I've affirmed that `list()` - w/o the filter passed in - always only returns this one entry. I had written a filter and removed it just to check this.

If I run the code from a program that run from the Unix command prompt it works fine. If I simply change the directory this Java SP it works fine.

If anyone can think of anything else to check I'd be obliged very much. Is there another Java method to try using other than those mentioned? Is there something in Unix that I might ask the DBA about that anyone can think of?

Comment: You've only shown one file in each directory so it's not clear that there is a problem; but what is returned in the array in both cases? The parent directory and permissions can certainly have an effect but I'd have thought you'd see an error. Are either of the the directory paths you're using actually a soft link to somewhere else? Wondering if you're getting information about the link, rather than where it's pointing, but just speculating clearly...

Comment: You show two `ls` commands, both returning just one file, and you're complaining your Java code returns only one file. Your problem is really not clear here.

Comment: Sorry that I confused you. I posted only the one file in each case only to show the permissions and other attributes of the file. There are many many other files and sub-directories in the directory I am "trying" to use, including six in all like the one shown in both places. In the directory I "can" read all these from the program clearly shows that it reads them all; and since it loads these pdf files into Oracle as BLOBS, I can also check the table to see if they are loaded - and doing so confirms what the program tells me. I like your idea, Alex, about the soft link - I will check that out

Comment: janos, I wrote: "If I simply change the directory this Java SP it works fine." ... which implies that there is a problem.

Comment: Alex, thank you too for editing the code portion of my entry - I apologize for not doing so myself.

Comment: I just tried something else. I copied the six files I mentioned to my $HOME directory, gave my directory 777 permissions, and pointed my Java procedure to look there. It does not recognize my $HOME directory as a File. What does Oracle need to read from any particular Unix directory/account, do you know?

Comment: The Oracle owning account (e.g. `oracle`) needs to be able to see the directory; but if your DBA can see it when logged in to that account then that shouldn't be an issue. If not check the permission of the the whole path - it needs at least `rx` on each level; you might have group permissions that let most people see it (`staff` group say) but Oracle isn't in that, and you don't have world permissions on some level.

Comment: Ah okay. I think I see what you mean. We have v-e-r-y tight control of permissions where I work and we go through these issues all the time. The really odd thing about this case - to me at least - is that it can see the directory, but only one file that is in it ... and that one file happens to be one, among several, sub-directories.

Comment: It seems that you were on the right track, Alex, as I am awaiting a grant to the specific directory from the DBA - who has security concerns about providing it, citing some article of Pete Finnigan about Java security problems. The reason that I can see that one sub-directory that I mentioned is that Oracle has rights to it and only it, not to the base directory I need access too. The alleged concern is something about Java having access to the directory, then any Java process in the DB can access it.

Comment: @BillJ - yes, that's a legitimate concern. Having a specific, isolated area Java can access makes sense but you have to balance security with utility. Opening up your home directory doesn't sound ideal though, since not only Java will be able to see it.

Comment: No, it won't be opening up my $HOME directory - that was just a test I did. It will be opening up a secure area. That said, most all of these areas are secure - now days what is not? Can you cite any particular concerns particular to Java?

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to an access control framework other than Unix file permissions, such as SELinux.